# Casting and arrays of generic class type in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

Is there a way to check instanceof for a generic class (not the generic type), and cast as well? E.g. I can do

```
if (obj instanceof Expression expr) {}
```

but not

```
if (obj instanceof Expression<T> expr) {}
```

if I'm trying to write a generic method. Is there also a way to create arrays of generic classes, e.g.

```
new Expression<T>[]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `List<Expression<T>>` instead. In Java, you cannot create an array of generic types.

Comment: I can probably do this because I'm doing a lot of hierarchy restructuring anyways. I asked about arrays because it had something to do with varargs, after a lot of work I can probably change from varargs to Lists

Comment: @WentinnLiao ничего не понял что Вы сказали :-)